# Area between halfcircle $r = 2$ and $r = 2 + 2\sin(\theta)$

Tags: integration, analysis, polar-coordinates

Hi I have to calculate the area between the halfcircle $r = 2$ and $r = 2 + 2\sin(\theta)$ for $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$.
I believe what they mean is the area above the x-axis and under the black line, as they talk about the halfcircle $r =2$, but I'm not sure if I interpreted it correct.

So what I did is, calculate the following integral:
\begin{align}
2\pi - \int_0^\pi \frac{1}{2} (2 + 2 \sin(\theta))^2
\end{align}but this gives $-\pi - 8$ which is negative? I would like some help.

[image]

Comment: Maybe it’s just simple geometry?

Comment: I think the region outside the circle and inside the limaçon is being described. That is, the region $D = \left\{(r,\theta) \mid 0 \leq \theta \pi,\ 2 \leq r \leq 2+2\sin\theta\right\}$.

Comment: Hmm it says between,how can it then be outside the circle? Do you mean outside the half  circle?

Comment: So i have to calculate the integral
\begin{align}
A = \int_2^{2+2\sin(\theta)} \int_0^\pi \frac{1}{2}(2 + 2\sin(\theta))^2 d(\theta)dr - 2\pi
\end{align}
? @MatthewLeingang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the region in question is the following:

$\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

which is enclosed by the two plane curves:

$$
\color{blue}{(x_1,y_1) = 2(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)
\quad \quad \text{with} \; \theta \in [0,\pi]}
$$

$$
\color{red}{(x_2,y_2) = (2+2\sin\theta)(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)
\quad \quad \text{with} \; \theta \in [0,\pi]}
$$

its area can be calculated by applying the **Gauss-Green theorem** in the plane:

$$
\mathcal{A} = \int_\pi^0 x_1\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial\theta}\text{d}\theta + \int_0^\pi x_2\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial\theta}\text{d}\theta = (-2\pi) + (8+3\pi) = 8+\pi.
$$

Of course, the same result is obtained by calculating a double integral:

$$
\small
\mathcal{A} 
= \int_0^\pi \left(\int_2^{2+2\sin\theta}\rho\,\text{d}\rho\right)\text{d}\theta
= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\pi\left(2+2\sin\theta\right)^2\text{d}\theta - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\pi(2)^2\text{d}\theta = (8+3\pi) - (2\pi) = 8+\pi.
$$

Comment: If i do it like this
$$
\mathcal{A} = \int_0^\pi \left(\int_2^{2+2\sin\theta}\rho\,\text{d}\rho\right)\text{d}\theta = 8+\pi.
$$
should I not substract the half circle $2\pi$?

Comment: I believe now the region being described is $D = \{(r, (\theta) \mid 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi, 2 \leq r \leq 2 + 2sin(\theta)\}$

Comment: But the graph is different from mine, so Im a bit confused, , is the blue curve the heartshaped one?

Comment: I see thanks! So should I calculate $$
\mathcal{A} = \int_0^\pi \left(\int_2^{2+2\sin\theta}r\text{d}r \right)\text{d}\theta - 2\pi
$$?

Comment: I have one other question about an integral that is related to this subject, I have posted it. Only if you have the time for it, I would appreciate it if you could look at it :)

Answer (score 2):

For $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$,  we have $\sin(\theta) \geq 0$, and therefore $r= 2 + 2 \sin(\theta) \geq 2$, meaning it falls outside of the circle. It follows that the area is given by

$$\frac{1}{2}\int _ 0 ^ {\pi}(2+2\sin(\theta))^2 -4 \ d\theta  = \int _ 0 ^ {\pi}4\sin(\theta) +2\sin(\theta)^2 d\theta = 8 + \pi$$

Your mistake was simply reversing the order of subtraction. I omitted the steps to finding the integral as you seem to be already familiar with the process from your question.

Comment: Hi I believe the region they describe is $D = \{(r, (\theta) \mid 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi, 2 \leq r \leq 2 + 2sin(\theta)\}$ , do you think so too? Or maybe something else?

Comment: Yes, we calculated the area of D. In words, D is saying "all points such that the angle from the x axis is between 0 and pi, and the distance from the origin is between 2 and 2+sin(the angle of the point from the origin)" - being a bit handwavy here as the concept of the x axis doesn't really make sense in polar coordinates, but I hope that clarifies things. The key is that whatever point we have, it's bigger or equal to 2 and less than or equal to 2+sin(theta).